# Passing values to another class

Tags: java

I have two classes **A** and **B** where, I create an object of the the class **B** in class **A** in the constructor as below:

```
B obj; 
public A(){
   obj = new B();
}
```

I need a function for example `returnValue()` in class **B** where it should send the values (int x & int y) to the class **A** (which creates the object of **B**)

Is there any way to do like this: the function returnValue() should send the values to class A without doing obj.returnValue() call.

Is there any way to do this.
Please help..
Thanks..

Comment: So you need the result of obj.returnValue() to properly construct the instance of A?

Comment: unclear. Please clarify what you want! What is x, y? THere's no argument in A(). What have you tried so far for B?

Comment: Your description is all over the place. obj will go away after the constructor completes.

Comment: B obj = new B(); - obj is only local to the constructor, it will be gone when the constructor goes out of scope

Comment: Is there any way to do like this: the function returnValue() should send the values to class A without doing obj.returnValue() call.

Comment: still unclear. what do you do with x,y in A where you "receive" them?

Comment: just think as two variables I can use it anywhere in class A

Comment: Why can't those variables be fields of `A`?

Comment: What do you meant by fields of A? I can't understand.

Comment: If you can't understand what is `fields of A` then maybe you need first read some books about Java and programming as a whole? It is so basic concept that it makes no sense to explain it there.

Answer (score 3):

You need to break this confusing dependency cycle. For instance you could pass B into A's constructor, so that you fully construct a B before creating an instance of A.

```
B b = new B();
ReturnValue rv = b.returnValue(); // where rv contains x and y
A = new A(b, rv.x, rv.y);
```

where A looks like

```
public class A {
    int x;
    int y;
    B b;
    public A(B b, int x, int y) {
        this.b = b;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
...
```

Creating objects in your constructor can make it hard to test your code. See this article on testability issues, [Flaw: Constructor does Real Work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/):

> Work in the constructor such as: creating/initializing collaborators, communicating with other services, and logic to set up its own state removes seams needed for testing, forcing subclasses/mocks to inherit unwanted behavior.  Too much work in the constructor prevents instantiation or altering collaborators in the test.